# Force page to be loaded before exiting function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I have a script more or less of the form

```
function a() {
  //do stuff
  $(window).onload = function() {
    //do stuff after loading
  }
  //do more stuff
 return true;
 }
```

I need to guarentee that the onload function occurs before function *a* returns anything. Is there a way to do this cleanly? I can't refactor the code to include everything in onload, it would require completely rewriting all the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try just having ONLOAD run everything

```
$(window).onload = function() {
//run onload

//run other functions


 }
```

Comment: Good answer because you can't make `function a` wait, without returning, for the window.onload event if it (`a`) is called beforehand!

Comment: that is was what I was thinking, it seemed more of creating some random hacks hoping it would work instead of just using onload to do everything.

Comment: I can't do that, it would require a massive refactor of the code, which is unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Get it here: http://jquery.com/

Then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: That has the same problem as the other answer, I can't do a massive refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded so each time a piece of script code runs, it runs to completion without getting interrupted. Event handlers (such as for "load" events) do not execute in the middle of running other script; There are no "wait" or "sleep" commands that allow pausing synchronous code in the middle of operation. So the short answer to your question is "no".

ECMA 2015 introduced [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) which under controlled circumstances allow executing and resuming a function at specified points within the function. **Although they currently lack support in some major browsers,** they do offer an alternative to other asynchronous coding techniques such as ES6 promises (which could be useful in refactoring a solution). The following Generator code for example:

```
function* a()
{   // do stuff
    window.addEventListener("load",
       function()
       {   // do stuff on load
           console.log("window.loaded");
           aGenerator.next();  // continue a();
       }
    );

    console.log("executing a() before yield");
    yield "'yield before window load'";
    console.log("executing a() after yield");

    // do stuff after load
    console.log("a() before return");
    return true;
}
var aGenerator = a();


function b()
{  console.log("calling a from b");
   var obj = aGenerator.next();
   console.log("b() received value %s", obj.value);
}
b();
```

- creates a Generator object `aGenerator` to run `a()` code using `aGenerator.next()`.
- `b` calls `aGenerator.next()' to run the first half of`a`.
- the value of the object passed back to `b` contains the value of the first yield expression.
- the window load event handler runs the second half of `a` by calling `aGenerator.next`. It will be passed back the value returned by `a`.

Without refactoring code however, this essentially pushes the synchronicity issue up a level of function call: `b` doesn't wait and returns before the load event handler is called.